# My parents did not claim me as a dependent but I marked the box on my return saying they did. How does this affect my stimulus?

Tags: dependents, amended-tax-return, stimulus

I'm a working 20 year old living at home with my parents and I thought my parents were going to claim me as a dependent so I marked the box saying I am a dependent. My parents did not claim me and I didn't bother to amend the return. How does this affect my stimulus? Will they look at my return or theirs?

Comment: Please add a country tag or edit it into the question.

Comment: Presumably, you will not receive money because you said you were a dependent, implying someone else (assuming the US here) will get the $500 for claiming you as a dependent. But since your parents *didn't* claim you as a depdendent, they won't either. That said, I thought the payments were going to be based on 2018 returns, since not everyone has file a 2019 return yet.

Comment: they are using 2018/2019 returns for two things: where to send the money; and to be able to estimate your AGI. If a person was a dependent in 2018/2019 they can still get the money in Spring 2021 if they qualify with 2020 numbers.

Comment: "and I thought my parents were going to claim me as a dependent so I marked the box saying I am a dependent" The box you checked actually says "Someone can claim:You as a dependent". Notice the "can". It means that someone meets the conditions in the law to claim you as a dependent. You don't need to know whether your parents actually claim you as a dependent or not. All that matters for this box is that they "can" claim you, which is true. So you checked the box correctly.

Comment: @user102008 We don’t know for sure whether or not OP answered that question correctly. It is entirely possible that OP is not able to be claimed as a dependent, and that is why the parents didn’t claim it.

Answer (score 4):

Did your parents pay for 50% or more of your living expenses for all of 2018, 2019, and 2020? If so, then they are eligible to claim you as a dependent (but do not have to). Note that even if you are not claimed as a dependent on someone else's return, if you *could be* claimed then you would **not** get the stimulus check. It depends on whether you *could* be claimed as a dependent, not whether you actually are.

I'm assuming that they paid more than 50% already for 2018 and 2019. Therefore, the only way you would get a stimulus check is if you payed more than 50% of your own living expenses for 2020. Then no one could claim you as a dependent and you would get the check as a credit when you file for 2020 next spring.

Unfortunately your parents would also not receive the $500 stimulus per child if they filed an amendment and claimed you since you are over 16. This is a [gross oversight](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/03/30/many-college-students-are-ineligible-for-a-stimulus-relief-check.html) and is kind of leaving college-age students and their parents out to dry...